# In Word how do I fix a missing top border on a nested table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

In Word I have a table with another table in one of its cells however the nested table is missing its top border.

[image]

How can I make it appear? I do have all the borders switched on for the nested table.

---

**Update from 2017**

This question was asked in 2012, but the issue is still here in Word 2016. It was recently submitted as a bug on Word's Uservoice: https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/32505451-bug-missing-top-bottom-borders-in-nested-tables. "Upvotes" for this bug are welcome as well as answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a blank line inside the container cell, before/on top of the inner table.
2. Select the inner table and ensure the *All Borders* option is selected (see screenshot below):

[image: Word 2010 table borders]

Edit: I see you've already done step 2. See if step 1 fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be cut off by the margin setting of the main table. There are a couple things you can do.

1. Increase the row height of the main table until it is no longer cut off.
2. Change the table properties of the main table to decrease the cell margins. You can get to this by selecting the table, RIGHT click, then choose `Table Properties > Options...`. Decrease the top and bottom margins to `0`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but neither of these seem to fix it.

Comment: @SiKeep a little late to the game, however, I had the same issue - the reasoning is there, it is because of the margin in the parent table. You can simply adjust the height of the table row manually and you will see it appear

Answer (score 2):

A workaround that I found when using Word 2016 :

Select the entire table, go to Table Properties > Borders and Shading,
and change the line width to 1 point instead of the default 1/2 point.

Comment: Yes, I also use this workaround. However, it looks very ugly after export to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the inner table -> Table Properties -> Borders and Shading

Set the top border's style to a double line:

[image]